# Xml tool to test xml data

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I'm in a project that loads a lot of XML from web services and I need to send the correct one and get the one I am expecting, a part that run the web app in Debug mode and add a breakpoint after getting the XML String, what can I have as a free plugin or even a trial program to let me see what XML is sending by my web application and what XML is been received by it?

Hope that I make sense.

Comment: Are you trying to sniff the transport stream?  What is being used as the client?

Comment: humm... I think that is the term! :) "Sniffing", I'm using ASP.NET as the Client, the Web Service is written in Java (using JBoss .NET)

Comment: Sorry, no help here... but I'm adding those details to your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what protocols you are using but [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) should show you for free :-)

> Wireshark's most powerful feature is
>   its vast array of display filters
>   (over 80000 as of version 1.0.5). They
>   let you drill drill down to the exact
>   traffic you want to see and are the
>   basis of many of Wireshark's other
>   features, such as the coloring rules.

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/

Comment: Wow, very nice application, thank you very much for this, it gives me what I just need: Seeing the document that I'm sending (screenshot at: http://tinyurl.com/8hbvch)